# How to break up Conditional probability on multiple evidence

Tags: probability

I want to calculate $\Pr(A \mid B,C)$.

What I have are $\Pr(A \mid B)$, $\Pr(A \mid  C)$, $\Pr(B \mid  A)$ and $\Pr(C \mid A)$. If it helps, all these 4 distributions are sigmoids.

What I don't have are the unconditional probabilities $\Pr(A)$,$\Pr(B)$,$\Pr(C)$, or any joint probability.

I know this is not sufficient to calculate what I want. If necessary, we can assume $B$ and $C$ are conditionally independent, or even fully independent (if possible, I want the assumptions to be as weak as possible). However, $A$ and $B$ are not independent, and $A$ and $C$ are not independent.

To generalize the question, what if I have more than 2 evidences: say I want to calculate $\Pr(A\mid B_1,B_2,\ldots,B_n)$, and I have $\Pr(A\mid B_i)$ for all $i$. What kind of independence assumption is necessary and sufficient?